# custom_data parameter is not triggered in terraform script

Tags: linux, shell, coding-style, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating virtual machine in azure using terraform in which i am passing custom data parameter which should actually trigger a yaml file which does few installations. But it's not being triggered. Could you please advise on this issue.`enter code here`

## Controller VM

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "controller-vm" {
name                  = "controller-vm"`enter code here`
location              = var.region

resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.controllernic.id]
vm_size               = var.ctr_instance_type

storage_os_disk {
    name              = "controller-os-disk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    disk_size_gb      = "400"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
}

storage_data_disk {
    name              = "controller-data-disk0"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "Empty"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    disk_size_gb      = "512"
    lun               = 1
}

storage_data_disk {
    name              = "controller-data-disk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "Empty"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    disk_size_gb      = "512"
    lun               = 2
}

storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "OpenLogic"
    offer     = "CentOS-CI"
    sku       = "7-CI"
    version   = "latest"
}

os_profile {
    computer_name  = "controller.${var.project_id}.local"
    admin_username = var.user
    custom_data = file(pathexpand(var.ctr_cloud_init_file))
}

os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
    ssh_keys {
        path     = "/home/${var.user}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
        key_data = file(pathexpand(var.ssh_pub_key_path))
    }
}

boot_diagnostics {
    enabled     = "true"
    storage_uri = azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount.primary_blob_endpoint
}

tags = {
    environment = var.project_id,
    user = var.user
}

}
```

The above code has a custom_data = file(pathexpand(var.ctr_cloud_init_file)) which should actually call the yaml file. which is not happened here.

Please find the yaml file i am using. ctr_cloud_init_file

```
users:
- name: bluedata
  groups: [sudo, wheel]
  shell: /bin/bash
  sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
  ssh-authorized-keys: 
  ### SSH Public Key Here
  - ssh-rsa ...

package_upgrade: true
packages: 
  - epel-release
  - firewalld
repo_update: true
repo_upgrade: all
```

Comment: The handling of `custom_data` is mostly done by `cloud-init` software installed in the VM image, and all Terraform is doing is making that raw data available for `cloud-init` to fetch and process. `cloud-init` usually generates logs about what it's doing that can be helpful in debugging problems like this. Where you'd find them will depend on which distribution you are using but hopefully you can find a file with a name containing "cloud-init" in `/var/log`, or maybe run `journalctl /usr/bin/cloud-init` on a systemd system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provision the Azure VM with the Cloud-init file, it's not a good way to load the file directly. For the Cloud-init, I would recommend you use the [`template_cloudinit_config`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/cloudinit_config.html), this is the special the provider for Cloud-init and its featureset is specialized for the features of cloud-init. And here is the example code:

```
data "template_file" "script" {
  template = file("cloud-init")
}

# Render a multi-part cloud-init config making use of the part
# above, and other source files
data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

  # Main cloud-config configuration file.
  part {
    filename     = "cloud-init"
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content      = data.template_file.script.rendered
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "controller-vm" {
...
os_profile {
    computer_name  = "controller.${var.project_id}.local"
    admin_username = var.user
    custom_data = data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered
}
...
}
```

Comment: I have made the changes based on your suggestion, but the clod inti file is not getting triggered. Please find the below changes made.
data "template_file" "script" {
  template = file("cloud-init-ctr.yaml")
}
data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

  # Main cloud-config configuration file.
  part {
    filename     = "init.cfg"
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content      = data.template_file.script.rendered
  }
}

Comment: @BabaDudekula It's my fault. The `filename` in the part should be the cloud-init name that you want to load.

Comment: Updated the script with file name. Still it's not being called. The file i am trying to call is a Yaml file. I have also changed the content from text to yaml in code. Please advise..data "template_file" "script" {
  template = file("cloud-init-ctr.yaml")
}
data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

  # Main cloud-config configuration file.
  part {
    filename     = "cloud-init-ctr.yaml"
    content_type = "yaml/cloud-config"
    content      = data.template_file.script.rendered
  }
}

Comment: @BabaDudekula Where do you put the file? In the same folder that the Terraform file you would deploy?

Comment: Yes indeed. Its in the same directory where the terraform is applied

Comment: @BabaDudekula Can you add an output to display what do you load from the file? `output "file" {
 value = data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered
}`. And share the yaml file in your question?

Comment: @BabaDudekula What does the output show? And are you sure the cloud-init work fine?

Comment: Hi Charles, I have updated the sample yaml in the question. Please have a look. I am doing some upgrades in the yaml. I have also added the output as suggested. Please see the below result.

file = H4sIAAAAAAAA/7xYa4+jSpL9jnT/Q261dHtGvhS2sY3tUUsDfmLjF+DnaNWTQPKwExJnJmCs1f72Fa6qvnW7+07vbktTnyAzIuNUciLihAck4Sjhol2mqA/iDPMohZRLcXRD3t+AQ7LEg7T89LTQFyNttV0OVfP4JFRv4g5RFpGkDxrP9V+EXwRRfG/0i/B29jBiKWERf9hCzqEbxijhfwN+hFECY/TpycUk88Qoibjocvpcwhg//X6ATWHCfETFUeISL0qCPlCciL8zeKCvvKSXk1yS+FHwi7CIYvQNzg/vbYBPKHBJwinBGFEhY4iyvgCACCpofeDgDHmQQwEAAAJKspT1wT9Y5pHfQBEihP/zscNChen efnefocc

Comment: Hi Charles.. the file output shows some huge data as above, still the clod init is not triggered.

Comment: @BabaDudekula That's the right output. Well, I would take a try if the cloud-init could work fine.

Comment: @BabaDudekula The cloud-init does not work. I assume it's not a cloud-init. And where do you find the VM image?

Comment: Hi @Charles Xu, I am using azure instance, so i am giving the Centos 7.7. You can see it in my question..! cloud-init doesn't work ?? Did you try it ?

Comment: @BabaDudekula Yes, I try it in the Azure portal. So the only problem is the cloud-init.

Comment: Hi @Charles Xu, Do you mean to say cloud-init doesn't work with Azure ..??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213600/discussion-between-charles-xu-and-baba-dudekula).

Comment: @BabaDudekula What way do you use to solve the issue? And if my answer works for you please accept it :-)

Comment: @BabaDudekula Is there any reason that you cannot accept the answer?

Comment: Hey Charles I did it.

Comment: @BabaDudekula First, don't give the message in that room, I cannot reply in that. Second, you need to give more messages for the question so that I can give the appropriate advice.